# MailBoxer: How should I do make it to send a notification through email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am studying a project [vish](https://github.com/ging/vish), which has an open source e-Learning platform http://vishub.org, in here, if some one comments another one's Excusion, one email will be sent. This ability is finished by using `mailboxer`.

But when I run a instance of `vish` locally, for validate `mailboxer`, I used a task sending some messages between all users, it worked fine, and I can find the new messages in the header's notification dropdown menu,  but I did not get a email when I commented some one Excursion like in `vishub`, and did not get any error message about `mailboxer`. According to my newbie experience, I guess that I should config a mail server, but I don't know how to config a mail server for `mailboxer`, it seems that there is no one discuss about it?

What should I do for enabling `mailboxer` email? Or any manual should I read? Or my question is not relative to `mailboxer`? Thanks in advance!

**Updated:**
According to @rick's reminding, I read some code of mailboxer:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
end
```

It make me clearer about the relationship between ActionMailer and MailBoxer!

Comment: You should use `ActionMailer` smpt_setting to send email locally (`localhost`)

Comment: @rick  How should I find the relationship between ActionMailer and Mailboxer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email wont't be sent in development unless you set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` in `environments/development.rb.` and also you should use `ActionMailer` to send email locally. For more information, you can refer this link [mailboxer](http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/)

Comment: your link really tell me how to do it, But not explain the interaction between mailboxer and actionmail